# how to pass an array of integers at a certain position to slidingdotsplash library?

Tags: java, android

I'm using a SlidingSplashScreen library by @Chabbal to slide between images and to show small dots below the images to keep track of the image I am showing. And using a fullScreenActivity to show the image in full screen. I want to show the pressed image in full screen but what happens that the fullScreenActivity starts from the first image not the one i pressed on it. here is my code the

> **MainActivity.java**

```
package com.hodhod.testproject;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import com.chabbal.slidingdotsplash.OnItemClickListener;
import com.chabbal.slidingdotsplash.SlidingSplashView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private int[] images = {

        R.drawable.heart,
        R.drawable.pexels,
        R.drawable.download

};

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final SlidingSplashView slidingSplashView = findViewById(R.id.sliding_splash_view);

    slidingSplashView.setImageResources(images);



    slidingSplashView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPagerItemClick(View view, int position) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FullScreenActivity.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("imagesId", images);
            myIntent.putExtra("position", position);
            startActivity(myIntent);

        }
    });

 }


}
```

> **activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.chabbal.slidingdotsplash.SlidingSplashView
    android:id="@+id/sliding_splash_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

</com.chabbal.slidingdotsplash.SlidingSplashView>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    />



</RelativeLayout>
```

> **FullScreenActivity.java**

```
package com.hodhod.testproject;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.chabbal.slidingdotsplash.SlidingSplashView;

public class FullScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


int[] imageId;
int position1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fullscreen);

    final SlidingSplashView slidingSplashViewFull = findViewById(R.id.sliding_splash_view_full);

    Intent myIntent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle =  myIntent.getExtras();

    if(bundle != null){
        imageId = bundle.getIntArray("imagesId");
        position1 = bundle.getInt("position");

        if(position1 == 0){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "image1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if(position1 == 1){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "image2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if(position1 == 2){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "image3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        slidingSplashViewFull.setImageResources(imageId);
    }

 }

}
```

> **fullscreen.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.chabbal.slidingdotsplash.SlidingSplashView
    android:id="@+id/sliding_splash_view_full"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</com.chabbal.slidingdotsplash.SlidingSplashView>

</LinearLayout>
```